# Alternative to override getters and setters

Tags: c#, encryption, getter-setter, postsharp

I have some sensitive data which I want to keep encrypted in the db and decrypt it on the fly in the code. Since it's an existing application, I would like the encryption/decryption process to run as low as possible in the pipeline, so I don't have to amend my services level. My first solution was amending getters and setters for selected properties, to run those through my encryption helper. Then I thought it would be nice to have this wrapped in an attribute. Found Post Sharp extension that could do it, but seems to be an overkill for this scenario. Are there any other alternatives to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Attributes are just meta-data; they don't do anything in and of themselves.  How exactly are you wanting to use attributes?

Comment: Is this an MVC app? Web forms? Windows forms?

Comment: @D Stanley Suppose to be called Aspect Oriented Programming. More here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868881/generate-custom-setter-using-attributes

Comment: @Matti Price It's an MVC app. Using EF

Comment: @Bartosz modifying getters and setters means you will never be able to use the encrypted data on the application end.  Don't know if this is what you want.  Have you considered Encrypt() and Decrypt() extension methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you use EF, you could build a wrapper on top of EF DbContext, a generic repository in which you could inject some hooks (interceptors).

One of those interceptors would be something like **ICryptographyInterceptor** which would handle based on the entity type the logic for encryption (on insert) or decrypt (on retrieve) and it would not pollute your business logic or models since these interceptors would handle this task.

An existing implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/iQuarc/DataAccess/tree/master/src/iQuarc.DataAccess).

If the project is too complex for this kind of changes, maybe a **ICryptographyService** for transforming entities would be a better solution.